# Como implementar um cliente para um webservice

Tags: java, web-service, eclipse

Gostaria de saber o que devo fazer para implementar um cliente para um `webservice` no Eclipse como uma `Dynamic Web Project`. Não posso gerar um cliente, logo tenho que começar do zero.

Comment: O `cliente` você está se referindo ao projeto?

Comment: O projeto é um cliente vai o utilizar um serviço já implementado.

Comment: Veja se eu entendi bem: Você quer desenvolver mais um "modulo" que vai se comunicar com o seu webservice que já está implantado ?? @EmanuellaGomes

Comment: Sim, @WellingtonAvelino

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Emanuella Gomes**, vou responder sua pergunta, com base nos seus comentários(sem especificar tecnologias ou regras necessárias) .

Como você já possui um webservice implantado você vai precisar dos métodos que já existem nele (caso não tenha você precisa criar e implantar novamente).

Exemplo de um método fictício no seu `Webservice`

```
    @GET
    @Path("/NovoModulo")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public String listarFaturas()
    {
    String gson = "";
    try
    {
        gson = new Gson().toJson(sincronizador.exportarFaturasREST());
    } catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        gson = e.getMessage();
    }
    return gson;
    }
```

Esse [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) eu particularmente gosto muito de usar porque podemos gerar um Json a partir de objetos e fica muito fácil de trabalhar.

Imagino que você já saiba criar e configurar um `Dynamic Web Project` então a partir disso, você precisa desenvolver seu novo modulo de acordo com as especificações(se existir) e implementar o acesso ao seu `WebService`.

Exemplo de acesso a esse método via Java no seu `DWP`:

```
private final String    metodo  = "NovoMetodo/";

 public List<FaturaPendente> listarFaturas() throws Exception
  {
    ConexaoWebService conexaoWebService = ConexaoWebService.getInstance();

    //Aqui você poderia criar uma validação para garantir que existe seus dados de oconexão
    //como ip, porta e nome do webservice

    //Aqui podemos chamar de "manha" você monta uma URL com os dados que foram verificados acima
    URL_WS = conexaoWebService.getProtocolor() + conexaoWebService.getIp() + conexaoWebService.getPorta() + conexaoWebService.getWebservice() + conexaoWebService.getClasse();

    //aqui é onde você monta o acesso ao seu método exemplo : 192.168.0.200:8080/WebService/NovoMetodo
    String[] resposta = new WebServiceCliente().get(URL_WS + metodo);
    List<Fatura> faturas = new ArrayList<Fatura>();
    //se a resposta for OK retornará 200 e você terá acesso aos dados do webservice
    if (resposta[0].equals("200"))
    {
        //utilizando o Gson 
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonArray array = parser.parse(resposta[1]).getAsJsonArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
        {
            FaturaImportado faturaImportada = gson.fromJson(array.get(i), FaturaImportado.class);

            Fatura fatura = new Fatura(faturaImportada.getCodigoCliente(), faturaImportada.getNomeCliente(), faturaImportada.getFormaPagamento());
            faturas.add(fatura);
        }

    } 

    return faturas;
}
```

Uma ideia para você é colocar em algum botão para disparar essa verificação, ou toda vez que o usuário entrar nesse modulo listar o que precisa.

** **Return faturas** : Como seu objeto já está preenchido neste momento você pode usa-lo da forma que melhor te atender e usar o resultado para exibir suas informações.

Lembrando que esse é um novo modulo, seu WebService precisa ter os métodos que vão ser consumidos por sua aplicação "Novo Modulo".